# Modify Google autocomplete predictions with my predictions

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am working on Gmaps project and using Gmaps JavaScript apiv3.
I have included an Gmaps search box which gives predictions by calling autocomplete service. But the predictions it fetches from the service is ok, in addition to that I want to show the prediction from my database as well.

I have created:

```
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
```

Searchbox gives the predictions as expected. But instead of default predictions given by autocompleteservice, I want to add my predictions as well.

Comment: If you are going to do this, make sure you follow Google Maps APIs Terms of Service https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions, in particular 10.3.b: "No modification of search results. You will not modify, reorder, augment, or manipulate search results in any way unless you explicitly notify the end user of your actions."

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any tutorials/guides in the internet and other SO questions about your question, maybe it is not possible because the prediction on the Autocomplete is based on the [Places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places).

You can check it in the [introduction part of Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete).

**Autocomplete** is a feature of the Places library in the Google Maps JavaScript API. You can use autocomplete to give your applications the type-ahead-search behavior of the Google Maps search field. When a user starts typing an address, autocomplete will fill in the rest.

In order to use `autocomplete`, you will need to load the Google Places library using the libraries parameter in the bootstrap URL for the Google Maps JavaScript API.

The only idea that the document may give you is How to retrieve predictions from the `autocomplete` service.

You can use `getPlacePredictions()` that returns place predictions. Note: A 'place' can be an establishment, geographic location, or prominent point of interest, as defined by the Places API. And `getQueryPredictions()` that returns an extended list of predictions, which can include places (as defined by the Places API) plus suggested search terms. For example, if the user enters 'pizza in new', the pick list may include the phrase 'pizza in New York, NY' as well as the names of various pizza outlets.

For more information just read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) about Autocomplete and check this [sample code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-queryprediction).

Comment: thanks for the answer, can share a way i can use a text field which looks like google search box and i can customize it to give predictions from my database as well as from google defaults also.